# "fprintf"-like function for file descriptors (i.e. int fd instead of FILE* fp)

Tags: c, file-io, printf, posix-api

Maybe I'm just missing it, but isn't there a function equivalent to fprintf for file descriptors, or even a way to temporarily flip-flop between them?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You could look into [`dprintf`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/dprintf) (**GNU extensions, not in C or POSIX**) :

> The functions dprintf() and vdprintf()
>   (as found in the glibc2 library) are
>   exact analogues of fprintf() and
>   vfprintf(), except that they output to
>   a file descriptor fd instead of to a
>   given stream.

**EDIT** As pointed by several of you in the comments, POSIX 2008 standardized these functions.

Comment: Thanks!  Very interesting, had no idea those existed.

Comment: Nor did I. Since this app is only going to run on Linux, this may be what I need. Cross-platform compatibility is not a concern, so using the GNU extension should be fine.

Comment: If portability is not a concern, go for these.

Comment: Indeed, POSIX 2008 standardized these functions.

Answer (score 9):

There is no C or POSIX (edit: prior to 2008) standard function to do `printf` on a file descriptor, but you can “open” a file descriptor as a `FILE *` with the POSIX-standard `fdopen(int desc, const char *mode)`. I'm not sure how well supported flipping back to using the descriptor directly is, but I'm guessing it might work if you flush the buffer first…

Of course you could just implement your own using something like `vsprintf`, but obviously you then have to take care of the buffering.

Comment: I was thinking of fdopen, but really don't want to "open" another handle, especially since IIRC calling fclose on that handle will close the underlying file descriptor as well. That would be a problem with the code I'm working on, as the routine may get either a file descriptor or a socket handle.

Comment: @Will: you can `fdopen` a file handled gotten from `dup`, so that the close won't affect your original fd

Comment: @Hasturkun: That's right, I forgot about dup. Not one of those functions I use regularly.

Answer (score 3):

For what it's worth, since `dprintf` is not a POSIX function, one could use the following if portability is an issue:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int
fdprintf ( int fd, size_t bufmax, const char * fmt, ... )
{
  char * buffer;
  int n;
  va_list ap;

  buffer = ( char * ) malloc ( bufmax );
  if ( !buffer )
    return 0;

  va_start ( ap, fmt );
  n = vsnprintf ( buffer, bufmax, fmt, ap );
  va_end ( ap );

  write ( fd, buffer, n );
  free ( buffer );
  return n;
}
```

Most likely would want to check the return value of `write`, but you get the general idea. Obviously, this does not buffer like the `FILE *` routines do; I was looking more for the format specifiers and the ability to build the character data that would be written to the file descriptor, rather than worrying about buffering the data as it is being written.

Comment: `dprintf` is POSIX (as of 2008), and functions that truncate data silently are usually a very bad idea. At least loop with larger buffers until it succeeds or return failure...

Comment: That's cool. My gcc version here is a little older and still shows `dprintf` as being only a GNU extension.

Answer (score 2):

No, there isn't as standard, but the two do different things. fprinft, as part of stdio, does things like buffer reads and writes, supports ungetc etc. Using a fd bypasses all that and calls the OS directly.

So they're not interchangeable. Flip flopping between them would screw up stdio buffering if nothing else

Comment: That's what I thought, but wasn't 100% sure.

Comment: Except... you can do `fdopen` and flip flopping works just fine as long as you remember to `flush()` when needed.

Comment: Probably, but not guaranteed, and probably doesn't work if you seek to a different position, and...

Answer (score 2):

You can open the file descriptor as a normal file that can be handled by `fprintf()` with [fdopen](https://linux.die.net/man/3/fdopen).

Comment: Just discovered `dprintf` up-thread which looks interesting, but reading this gave me a thought: how bad would it be to pass a `fd` into a function and call `fdopen(fd)` *every single function call*, if performance wasn't a concern? I'm imagining this would probably leak memory like crazy at the very least. (And then there are implementation differences to take into account, perhaps some implementations would leak and some wouldn't.) Or maybe this *would* work?